# Javascript: string to Float

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects. objects have "Poured, Sold, Loss and Variance" properties as string. I want to convert string to float. I need to persist that comma separator and double point precision. Here is the example array of objects.

```
[{"ID":"September-2016", "Product":"September-2016", "Poured":"111,759.07", "Sold":"107,660.97", "Loss":"-4,098.10", "Variance":"-3.67", "startDate":"2016-09-01", "endDate":"2016-09-22"}, {"ID":"November-2015", "Product":"November-2015", "Poured":"53,690.25", "Sold":"52,953.60", "Loss":"-736.65", "Variance":"-1.37", "startDate":"2015-11-20", "endDate":"2015-11-30"}, {"ID":"May-2016", "Product":"May-2016", "Poured":"156,401.65", "Sold":"151,192.51", "Loss":"-5,209.14", "Variance":"-3.33", "startDate":"2016-05-03", "endDate":"2016-05-31"}, {"ID":"March-2016", "Product":"March-2016", "Poured":"49,260.22", "Sold":"49,399.14", "Loss":"138.92", "Variance":"0.28", "startDate":"2016-03-01", "endDate":"2016-03-09"}, {"ID":"June-2016", "Product":"June-2016", "Poured":"162,126.88", "Sold":"161,718.62", "Loss":"-408.26", "Variance":"-0.25", "startDate":"2016-06-01", "endDate":"2016-06-30"}, {"ID":"July-2016", "Product":"July-2016", "Poured":"160,185.68", "Sold":"154,882.40", "Loss":"-5,303.28", "Variance":"-3.31", "startDate":"2016-07-01", "endDate":"2016-07-31"}, {"ID":"January-2016", "Product":"January-2016", "Poured":"355,509.26", "Sold":"179,696.72", "Loss":"-175,812.54", "Variance":"-49.45", "startDate":"2016-01-01", "endDate":"2016-01-31"}, {"ID":"February-2016", "Product":"February-2016", "Poured":"150,980.73", "Sold":"146,248.72", "Loss":"-4,732.01", "Variance":"-3.13", "startDate":"2016-02-01", "endDate":"2016-02-29"}, {"ID":"December-2015", "Product":"December-2015", "Poured":"167,843.42", "Sold":"163,732.95", "Loss":"-4,110.47", "Variance":"-2.45", "startDate":"2015-12-01", "endDate":"2015-12-31"}, {"ID":"August-2016", "Product":"August-2016", "Poured":"168,853.51", "Sold":"160,024.84", "Loss":"-8,828.67", "Variance":"-5.23", "startDate":"2016-08-01", "endDate":"2016-08-31"}]
```

I need like

```
[{"ID":"September-2016", "Product":"September-2016", "Poured":111,759.07, "Sold":107,660.97, "Loss":-4,098.10, "Variance":-3.67, "startDate":"2016-09-01", "endDate":"2016-09-22"}, {"ID":"November-2015", "Product":"November-2015", "Poured":53,690.25, "Sold":52,953.60, "Loss":-736.65, "Variance":-1.37, "startDate":"2015-11-20", "endDate":"2015-11-30"}, {"ID":"May-2016", "Product":"May-2016", "Poured":156,401.65, "Sold":151,192.51, "Loss":-5,209.14, "Variance":-3.33, "startDate":"2016-05-03", "endDate":"2016-05-31"}, {"ID":"March-2016", "Product":"March-2016", "Poured":49,260.22, "Sold":49,399.14, "Loss":138.92, "Variance":0.28, "startDate":"2016-03-01", "endDate":"2016-03-09"}, {"ID":"June-2016", "Product":"June-2016", "Poured":162,126.88, "Sold":161,718.62, "Loss":-408.26, "Variance":-0.25, "startDate":"2016-06-01", "endDate":"2016-06-30"}, {"ID":"July-2016", "Product":"July-2016", "Poured":160,185.68, "Sold":154,882.40, "Loss":-5,303.28, "Variance":-3.31, "startDate":"2016-07-01", "endDate":"2016-07-31"}, {"ID":"January-2016", "Product":"January-2016", "Poured":355,509.26, "Sold":179,696.72, "Loss":-175,812.54, "Variance":-49.45, "startDate":"2016-01-01", "endDate":"2016-01-31"}, {"ID":"February-2016", "Product":"February-2016", "Poured":150,980.73, "Sold":146,248.72, "Loss":-4,732.01, "Variance":-3.13, "startDate":"2016-02-01", "endDate":"2016-02-29"}, {"ID":"December-2015", "Product":"December-2015", "Poured":167,843.42, "Sold":163,732.95, "Loss":-4,110.47, "Variance":-2.45, "startDate":2015-12-01, "endDate":"2015-12-31"}, {"ID":"August-2016", "Product":"August-2016", "Poured":168,853.51, "Sold":160,024.84, "Loss":-8,828.67, "Variance":-5.23, "startDate":"2016-08-01", "endDate":"2016-08-31"}]
```

Please let me know how can I achieve that.

Sorry I mentioned it as "**String to Integer**" initially that should be "**String to Float**"

Comment: You CANNOT have a number with comma separators and specific precision in JS. There is a single numeric type that JavaScript knows and it doesn't format it.

Comment: If you want to preserve the precision, multiply all the numbers by 100 and round to the nearest integer, and use that instead of the fractions.

Comment: You CAN produce the desired output however - but it will be a string, not a number, nor would it be easily convertible to number in JS.

Comment: @e-neko why would it not be easily convertable to number? Essentially all you do is remove thousand separators, replace the fraction separator (if altered) then pass it through `Number`.

Comment: I almost called it a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2843897/1233251)... But this one includes the misconception of keeping formatting and precision rules in a number.

Comment: @vlaz indeed, but it will involve finding the correct separators (and not, accidentally, commas), and in general will not be trivial.

Comment: In addition to @vlaz 's comment which is 100% correct (if it has commas in it then it necessarily is a string), you cannot have decimals in an Integer.

Comment: @e-neko not _trivial_ but still easy. As long as you keep your numeric value contained. Sure, parsing it out from a string that contains whatever will be impossible but I don't think it's as hard as you make it out to be. I work with internationalised money values at work and, trust me, thousand separators are really trivial. If you have to work out some of the separators used around the world by yourself, that will be hard.

Comment: @nurdyguy JavaScript does not have integers, though. The number `1.00` and `1` are literally the same thing. JS will just show fractions if any and truncates the displayed number otherwise

Comment: *I want to convert string to integer. I need to persist that comma separator and double point precision.* Why do you want to do this? The desired output you show is invalid JSON, since the numbers have an invalid format. What are you planning to do with it, assuming you could create it?

Comment: Assume you want a float (not an integer). Integer can't hold decimals

Comment: @vlaz I agree, a big part of the confusion comes from JS being loosely typed.  I suppose my point is that if you try to do things like `parseInt` you are going to lose the precision.  In the op he has 111,759.07 and that clearly is not possible with any integer-ish operation.  Really this points back to the op being fairly poorly formulated.

Comment: @nurdyguy ah, I completely missed that the OP referenced integers, sorry. Indeed, integer = whole number and if you `parseInt(1.23)` you will get `1`.

Comment: @Endless yes float also be fine. Please let me know is that possible to get

Comment: @torazaburo once again sorry to mentioned it as integer. That is a float. Actually I like to do array sorting by Poured, Sold, Loss(based on situation). Sort with current is not happening. So I thought to convert string to float. Then sort definitely works right. That's the major goal.

Comment: For sorting, you do not need commas, nor some fixed precision, right? So why do you talk about "persisting" them? You can convert the strings into numbers just by removing commas, as in `Number(value.replace(/,/g, '')`. By the way, JavaScript has no "floats"; it has **numbers**.

Comment: @torazaburo Yah, but javascript has parseFloat and parseInt. Still variables are loosely typed (not the number per say). It's just the definition of what he want the number to be represented in. On the other hand TypedArray can only be represented by Intenger and doing `2.3|0` will actually cast the float to be switched to a Integer internally by v8, SpiderMonkey for example - So there is some ways you can define a variable to be a float or a int

Comment: @torazaburo and all Thank you much for your reply. Now I got an idea. Actually I want to show Poured, Sold, Loss values as table. With readable(should have precision and comma separator) and while click on header should be sort(both ascending descending) So I thought to convert this string to float can meet these 2 requirements. From your reply and Endless reply got an idea.  To show I can use the existing field and append more field for sorting with Float(without comma separator). Learned two lesson from this. Float & integers shouldn't contain comma and add more field for other purpose.

Comment: Lesson: javascript (or any other data) shouldn't try to keep information (date, boolean, numbers, etc) as string they need to be programmable usable and then be presented in the view (html) as human readable so you can keep the logic (programable part). Ultimately you should do something like `div.innerText = makeReadable(flotingNumber)` and not as two separate fields where one is sortable and the other is readable. Try to think of it like a controller/view

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a float, then i assume that it need to be programmable usable and don't even need to be human readable - cuz the only way you will get that is by keeping it as a string...

```js
var data = [{"ID":"September-2016", "Product":"September-2016", "Poured":"111,759.07", "Sold":"107,660.97", "Loss":"-4,098.10", "Variance":"-3.67", "startDate":"2016-09-01", "endDate":"2016-09-22"}, {"ID":"November-2015", "Product":"November-2015", "Poured":"53,690.25", "Sold":"52,953.60", "Loss":"-736.65", "Variance":"-1.37", "startDate":"2015-11-20", "endDate":"2015-11-30"}, {"ID":"May-2016", "Product":"May-2016", "Poured":"156,401.65", "Sold":"151,192.51", "Loss":"-5,209.14", "Variance":"-3.33", "startDate":"2016-05-03", "endDate":"2016-05-31"}, {"ID":"March-2016", "Product":"March-2016", "Poured":"49,260.22", "Sold":"49,399.14", "Loss":"138.92", "Variance":"0.28", "startDate":"2016-03-01", "endDate":"2016-03-09"}, {"ID":"June-2016", "Product":"June-2016", "Poured":"162,126.88", "Sold":"161,718.62", "Loss":"-408.26", "Variance":"-0.25", "startDate":"2016-06-01", "endDate":"2016-06-30"}, {"ID":"July-2016", "Product":"July-2016", "Poured":"160,185.68", "Sold":"154,882.40", "Loss":"-5,303.28", "Variance":"-3.31", "startDate":"2016-07-01", "endDate":"2016-07-31"}, {"ID":"January-2016", "Product":"January-2016", "Poured":"355,509.26", "Sold":"179,696.72", "Loss":"-175,812.54", "Variance":"-49.45", "startDate":"2016-01-01", "endDate":"2016-01-31"}, {"ID":"February-2016", "Product":"February-2016", "Poured":"150,980.73", "Sold":"146,248.72", "Loss":"-4,732.01", "Variance":"-3.13", "startDate":"2016-02-01", "endDate":"2016-02-29"}, {"ID":"December-2015", "Product":"December-2015", "Poured":"167,843.42", "Sold":"163,732.95", "Loss":"-4,110.47", "Variance":"-2.45", "startDate":"2015-12-01", "endDate":"2015-12-31"}, {"ID":"August-2016", "Product":"August-2016", "Poured":"168,853.51", "Sold":"160,024.84", "Loss":"-8,828.67", "Variance":"-5.23", "startDate":"2016-08-01", "endDate":"2016-08-31"}]

data.forEach(function(item){
  item.Poured = parseFloat(item.Poured.replace(/,/g, ''))
  // item.Sold = parseFloat(item.Sold.replace(/,/g, ''))
  // item.Variance = parseFloat(item.Variance.replace(/,/g, ''))
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. In my mind I fixed need to show values with comma separator and double point precision and then while user clicks header should be sort. So changing string to float(comma separator) achieving the both requirement. Now I got clear idea to add one more field for sorting purpose and use existing field for show on page. You are very awesome. For this I tried long time today

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sequence of operations:

1. replace "," with ""
2. parseFloat()
3. toFixed(2)

Comment: The third step will give you a string.

Comment: But that creates a string, not an integer, as the OP incorrectly imagines is possible.

Comment: Yes, but if the value is to have two decimals, it needs to be a string.

Comment: Then you should point out that what the OP is asking for is impossible and/or meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You use the term "[integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)", but I assume you mean "numbers" (not "floats", since that concept does not exist in JS)--since integers have no decimal part by definition.

Numbers in JavaScript do not and cannot have thousands separators, nor specifiable precision--in other words, `1.00` is exactly equivalent to `1`. Therefore, you cannot convert a string to some non-existent form of integer with separators and precision.

If you're so inclined, check out the section of the ES spec about [numeric literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals).

Thousands separators and/or some fixed precision are aspects of the **representation** of a number, taking the form of a string.

Comment: mistakenly typed string to integer. My mind set to get "123, 567.75" to 123,456.75. Thank you so much for your reference

Answer (score 0):

what you are expecting is wrong & you can get the result as an array of numbers or coma separated string, please refer below code and output.

```
var RESULT = YOUR_RESPOSE.map(function(a){
['Poured','Sold', 'Variance', 'Loss'].forEach(function(v){
 if(typeof a[v] === "string"){
    // if you want as an array
    a[v] = a[v].split(',').map(function(s){return isNaN(s) ? s : (+s).toFixed(2)});
    // if you want as an string
    //a[v] = a[v].split(',').map(function(s){return isNaN(s) ? s : (+s).toFixed(2)}).join(',');
 }
});

return a;

})



"[{"ID":"September-2016","Product":"September-2016","Poured":["111.00","759.07"],"Sold":["107.00","660.97"],"Loss":["-4.00","98.10"],"Variance":["-3.67"],"startDate":"2016-09-01","endDate":"2016-09-22"},{"ID":"November-2015","Product":"November-2015","Poured":["53.00","690.25"],"Sold":["52.00","953.60"],"Loss":["-736.65"],"Variance":["-1.37"],"startDate":"2015-11-20","endDate":"2015-11-30"},{"ID":"May-2016","Product":"May-2016","Poured":["156.00","401.65"],"Sold":["151.00","192.51"],"Loss":["-5.00","209.14"],"Variance":["-3.33"],"startDate":"2016-05-03","endDate":"2016-05-31"},{"ID":"March-2016","Product":"March-2016","Poured":["49.00","260.22"],"Sold":["49.00","399.14"],"Loss":["138.92"],"Variance":["0.28"],"startDate":"2016-03-01","endDate":"2016-03-09"},{"ID":"June-2016","Product":"June-2016","Poured":["162.00","126.88"],"Sold":["161.00","718.62"],"Loss":["-408.26"],"Variance":["-0.25"],"startDate":"2016-06-01","endDate":"2016-06-30"},{"ID":"July-2016","Product":"July-2016","Poured":["160.00","185.68"],"Sold":["154.00","882.40"],"Loss":["-5.00","303.28"],"Variance":["-3.31"],"startDate":"2016-07-01","endDate":"2016-07-31"},{"ID":"January-2016","Product":"January-2016","Poured":["355.00","509.26"],"Sold":["179.00","696.72"],"Loss":["-175.00","812.54"],"Variance":["-49.45"],"startDate":"2016-01-01","endDate":"2016-01-31"},{"ID":"February-2016","Product":"February-2016","Poured":["150.00","980.73"],"Sold":["146.00","248.72"],"Loss":["-4.00","732.01"],"Variance":["-3.13"],"startDate":"2016-02-01","endDate":"2016-02-29"},{"ID":"December-2015","Product":"December-2015","Poured":["167.00","843.42"],"Sold":["163.00","732.95"],"Loss":["-4.00","110.47"],"Variance":["-2.45"],"startDate":"2015-12-01","endDate":"2015-12-31"},{"ID":"August-2016","Product":"August-2016","Poured":["168.00","853.51"],"Sold":["160.00","24.84"],"Loss":["-8.00","828.67"],"Variance":["-5.23"],"startDate":"2016-08-01","endDate":"2016-08-31"}]"
```

Comment: `.split(',').map` I don't think that's what you want to do - you are converting each chunk of the comma separated number.

Comment: @Manivannan Sorry I couldn't get what you are trying to tell from your answer. Can you please explain bit more