# How to convert a string to number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, string-conversion

I can't figure it out how to convert this string `82144251` to a number.

Code:

```
var num = "82144251";
```

If I try the code below the `.toFixed()` function converts my number back to a string...

Question update:
I'm using the Google Apps Script editor and that must be the issue...

```
num = parseInt(num).toFixed() // if I just do parseInt(num) it returns 8.2144251E7
```

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function does, in fact, return a string, not a number.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: you're looking for `Number(num)`

Comment: Also note that `8.2144251E7` is precisely the same value as  `82144251`.

Comment: @georg the same issue with Number(num)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried with .toFixed(0), it still returns a string

Comment: @Pointy I need it to be exactly  `82144251`, without any decimals

Comment: @PavelValeriu Why are you calling `.toFixed()` at all? `parseInt()` returns a number, that's all you need.

Comment: @PavelValeriu That's because `.toFixed()` always returns a string as the documentation I provided explains. See my answer below for a fix.

Comment: I'm confused why the result of `parseInt` isn't what you're after.

Comment: @PavelValeriu: what issue? "parseInt(num) returns 8.2144251E7"? - no it doesn't

Comment: @PavelValeriu `8.2144251E7` **is** exactly `82144251`. They are two ways of writing the same numeric value. Perform an `===` comparison if you don't believe me. When you `alert()` or `console.log()` a number, it gets converted back to a string for display purposes.

Comment: @PavelValeriu: `num =+ "num";` is the problem. What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: @PavelValeriu: ok, I think it's `Logger.log` that corrupts your data. Try inserting `num` in the document, it should be all right

Comment: @georg I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Converting String to Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can convert a string to number using unary operator '+' or parseInt(number,10) or Number()

check these snippets

```js
var num1a = "1";
console.log(+num1a);

var num1b = "2";
num1b=+num1b;
console.log(num1b);


var num3 = "3"
console.log(parseInt(num3,10));


var num4 = "4";
console.log(Number(num4));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: While is correct that `+num` converts the string in to a number, I personally would not use that. It always looks like the `+` was an accidental left over.

Comment: ...And can lead to confusion between that and `+=`

Comment: @Scott Marcus. I do not believe +num is confusing at all. It's a sufficient way to change the type with less code.

Comment: It works here, but please check my updated question. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisHaugen I didn't say `+num` was confusing, I said `num=+num` can be easily confused with `num+=num`.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're looking for the `Number()` functionality here:

```
var num = "82144251"; // "82144251"
var numAsNumber = Number(num); // prints 82144251
typeof num // string
typeof numAsNumber // number
```

You can read more about `Number()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is widely considered a bad practice to use the `Number()`, `String()` and `Boolean()` constructor functions.

Comment: Hey @ScottMarcus thanks for the heads up on that. We learn something new every day :) Would you be able to help me understand why that is?

Comment: @ScottMarcus why is `Number()` a bad practice? `parseInt` and `Number` have different purpose.  If I want to accept `100px` or similar as input then `parseInt` will be useful, if I want to ensure that the string only contains numbers (including trailing and leading spaces, `e` notation and hex)  then `Number()` would give me the correct result.

Comment: @Dave Cooper Because they are a bit of an anti-pattern. They are constructors that you don't have to use with `new` and we have other more intuitive means to do the jobs.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so you'd say parseInt is a more sane solution? If so, why?

Comment: @DaveCooper `Number()` creates a number object behind the scenes, rather than just sticking with a type, which (depending on implementation) incurs more overhead and is easily confused with `new Number()`. This is true of `String()` and `Boolean()` as well.

Answer (score 5):

No questions are dumb.

### a quick answer:

to convert a string to a number you can use the [unary plus.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

```
var num = "82144251";

num = +num;
```

Doing `num = +num` is practically the same as doing `num = num * 1;` it converts the value in a to a number if needed, but after that it doesn't change the value.

Comment: So what happens when the string contains a non-numeric character?

Comment: It should evaluate to NAN, however, your question does not specify it needs to handle non numbers. Just that `num = parseInt(num).toFixed()` returns a string with an E in it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num = "82144251";
num = parseInt(num).toFixed()
console.log(num, typeof num); // string
num = parseFloat(num);
console.log(num, typeof num); // number
```

Comment: Ok, but the result is `8.2144251E7` instead of `82144251`

Comment: @PavelValeriu That's not what the result is when I run the code. Did you run the snippet?

Comment: It works here, but please check my updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

var intNum = parseInt("82144251", 10); // intNum is number

Answer (score -1):

I use num-0, since it is easier for inline use.