# Really strange error post with google script

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a post with google Apps.

```
function makePost(url,page,status,token) {
var form = {
    "page" : 1,
    "statuses[]": status.toString().toLowerCase(),    
}
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers' : {"Authorization" : "BASIC "+token},
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload' : form,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
return jsonResponse;}
```

The problem seems to be that page is being past as 1.0 what makes the destination url return an error when tries to cast.

Already tried the answer in [How to convert a string to number using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685562/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number-using-google-apps-script) .

I cant pass it as a String , because in that case the API returns the result with an strange behaviour.

Is it possible to pass this as Integer without being change it to 1.0 ?

Any suggestion or help will be helpfull,
thanks

UPDATE: So , i couldnt find a way to accomplish this. UrlFetchApp changes it every time. Lucky for me we could solve it by order the response in the API , and the behaviour passing a string stoped being erratic.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: what will happen if you pass 1 as a string as "page" : "1" ?

Comment: no , they are not asynchonous. I debug and see that the request is being send with 1.0

Comment: If i passed as "1" , it works but is not what API expected so doesnt give me the rigth answer. With curl works ok with -d "page=1" and incorrectly with -d "page='1'" @ChrisChen

Comment: I would argue that this is an issue with your form not recognizing that 1.0 is the same as 1. In [JavaScript, all numbers are `float`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type). You cannot have a number that does not have the decimal portion.

Comment: @RodrigoLopezGuerra assuming you do not have control over the server end reciving this posts? Then how about 'payload' : JSON.stringify(form) ?

Comment: @ChrisChen i tried , but when i stringify the data , parameters are ignored in destination API

Answer (score 1):

Same here connecting with Stripe REST which enforces a form-based body. It must be a bug of UrlFetchApp.

When I use

```
payload: {
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'USD',
}
```

UrlFetchApp always encoded it into, note the decimal .0

```
"payload":"amount=1000.0&currency=USD"
```

But I resolved it by converting it to a String.

```
payload: {
  amount: String(1000),
  currency: 'USD',
}
```

Oddly, the payload will now be encoded correctly into

```
"payload":"amount=1000&currency=USD"
```

since the [form-urlencoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.1) doesn't specify the type of value, in this case, either a numeric String or an Integer. It's the server's implementation for interpreting the value.

Comment: Did you miss the comment above? **All** numbers in JavaScript are floating point. There is no `int`.