# Script does not export TopImpressionPercentage and AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage as digits in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, awql

I’ve created a script that exports campaign results to a Google Sheets file. When I implemented the script on September 29th, the data was exported perfectly. See example below (notice that the last four numbers are right-aligned because they're digits).

| Month | AccountDescriptiveName | CampaignName | Impressions | SearchImpressionShare | **TopImpressionPercentage** | **AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-01 | Account name | Campaign name | 2800 | 90.82% | **0.73** | **0.73** |

However, something changed in the output two weeks ago. The columns TopImpressionPercentage and AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage were exported differently.

| Month | AccountDescriptiveName | CampaignName | Impressions | SearchImpressionShare | **TopImpressionPercentage** | **AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-03-01 | Account name | Campaign name | 2800 | 90.82% | **0.73** | **0.73** |

The issue here is that TopImpressionPercentage and AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage have *different cell properties*. Google Sheets doesn’t see these cells as *digits* but as *text* (I guess). Now the goal of this export is that we automatically make calculations in a different sheet based on these number. These automatic calculations fail now because these two columns don’t work anymore. Manually changing the cell properties in Google Sheets is not a solution.

I have no idea how this has changed. I haven’t made any changes to the script. I’ve tried to run the script to a different Google Sheets file but without any difference.

Here's the script. My apologies for the incorrect indenting, but the focus here is on the elements that the script contains.

```
function main(){
var sheetURL = 'URL';
var tabName = 'Tabname';

var QUERIES = [{'query' : 'SELECT Month, AccountDescriptiveName, CampaignName, Labels, '
            + 'Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, SearchImpressionShare, TopImpressionPercentage, AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage '
            + 'FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
            + 'WHERE Impressions > 0 '
            + 'DURING 20190101,20220101', 
              'spreadsheetUrl' : sheetURL,
              'tabName' : tabName,
              'reportVersion' : 'v201809'
       }            
      ];

  var query;
  var spreadsheetUrl;
  var tabName;
  var reportVersion;

 for(var i in QUERIES) {
  var queryObject = QUERIES[i];
  query = queryObject.query;
  spreadsheetUrl = queryObject.spreadsheetUrl;
  tabName = queryObject.tabName;
  reportVersion = queryObject.reportVersion;
 }

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(query, {apiVersion: reportVersion});
  report.exportToSheet(sheet);
}
```

I was forwarded from the Google Ads Scrips Direct Support as everything works as it should in the [Campaign Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report#topimpressionpercentage). Because "the [Google Ads Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) utilizes Google Apps Script's Spreadsheet to actually extract the report to your spreadsheet", they recommended me reaching out to [Apps Script team](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support).

I hope that you are able to help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say that you wrote a script that does something and in that script something stopped working and you don't show the code itself - so it's hard to advise anything in this situation. Perhaps you can find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685562/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number)

Comment: @Sergey Valid point, added the script.

Comment: I think in your case it would be easier, after adding the data using the `.exportToSheet()` method, to read the data from these two columns and convert them from strings to numbers using any of the methods suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685562/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number)

Comment: Please bear with me as this is the first time I wrote a script in AWQL. I have no idea what I should write in order to read those two columns. I think that I should declare it first, but I can't wrap my head around how to do that. Could you give me more advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse the values such that they end up matching the type you need for your calculations.

The thing with Apps Script is that when using `getValue`, the method will end up returning a value of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String`, depending on the value of the cell. Therefore, if the cell is indeed formatted to store values of type `text`, the value returned in the script will be of type `String`.

To fix this, simply do the following:

```
var topImpressionPercentage = Number(rangeTop.getValue());
var absoluteTopImpressionPercentage = Number(rangeAbs.getValue());
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the initial code. Where do you think that I should add this part?