# Allowing/replacing comma as number separator for input type="number" using Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

I am using Rails and I have the following:

```
<%= item.number_field :price, step: 0.01, class: "item_price" %>
```

which results in the following html:

```
<input step="0.01" class="item_price" name="something" id="something" type="number">
```

My website is targeted for Bulgarian audience where official number separator is comma ","

e.g. someone is very likely to type "5,90", but this is not a valid number, and it won't pass Rails/html built in validation.

I tried to replace the comma with a "." using javascript, but it seems that for number input field, I can't get the value at all if it is not a valid number, which "5,90" isn't, so I am stuck.
I used the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function (){
    alert(this)
    alert(this.value)
    var v = this.value.replace(/,/g,'.');
    if (v!=this.value)
    this.value = v;
    alert(this.value)
  });
});
```

When I type 1 in the field,  alerts say "1", when I type "1," alerts are empty.

The only possible solution I could think of is changing the field to a text field, but this way I would loose all the nice rails extras, so I'd like to avoid it.

What I want is "5,90" to be treated the same as "5.90". Whichever the user inputs should get valid.

Any Javascript, JQuery or Rails solution is welcome.
fine

Update: on Chrome I am not even allowed to type "," in the field, which is not nice because I press the comma on the keyboard, and simply nothing happens, not nice UX

My initial tests were on FF, where I can type "comma" but it is invalid

On Android, built in browser: I get number keyboard where only "." is present, which is OK

Comment: `I tried to replace the comma with a "." using javascript, but it seems that for number input field, I can't get the value at all if it is not a valid number`. Are you sure about it ? When you query an input with type=number in javascript, It will replace all commas by dot, ie : 5,90 will become 5.90

Comment: Just FWIW, "number separator" is a bit vague, as there are two standard number separators (at least), the *decimal separator* (what I believe you mean above, often called the decimal point) and the *thousands separator* (or perhaps more generically, the *grouping separator* as there are some places that don't group by thousands).

Comment: @Pierre Capo, I have included the code I tried to use to replace the comma in my question

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. I mean the decimal separator. Both comma, and dot should be treated as decimal separators for my purpose

Comment: What you're describing seeing doesn't fit with my experience of interacting with `input `fields. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Obviously, when people run it they'll see their decimal separator rather than yours, but we can still probably work with it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I have created this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6atubo5w/5/, and it shows that when you type comma in the field, the value gets from 1, to empty

Comment: @Jeni - Please put the example **in** the question, don't just link to it. (But don't incorporate answers into it.) The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. (And questions shouldn't be edited to incorporate answers.) Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. That's why I pointed you at the on-site Stack Snippets.

Comment: Separately: `alert` is a terrible way to show values. Use the console.

Answer (score 1):

I made some researches and that is a super intersting topic.
A curious thing is that by default  will use local conventions but the browser will convert it as a dot decimal separator. For instance, if you are from Bulgaria, if you type 5,90 in your input :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function (){
    console.log(this.value); // will still log 5.90 (dot separator)
  });
});
```

To sum up, in both cases, if someone from the UK writes 5.90, or if someone from Bulgaria writes 5,90, the JavaScript value of the input will be 5.90.

For whatever reason, if you are intersted to know which decimal separator use your client, this function will return his decimal separator :

```
function whatDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
    return n;
}
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074660/with-a-browser-how-do-i-know-which-decimal-separator-that-the-client-is-using#1308446)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my findings on the problem even though it is not fully solved, they are pure HTML have nothing to do with Rails.
This is a very good article on the matter: https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Locale-based_forms.

So the partial solution I found is adding "lang" => "bg-BG" (Rails code) / lang="bg-BG" (html):

```
<%= item.number_field :price, step: 0.01, class: "item_price", "lang" => "bg-BG" %>
```

What it does:
in FF:

- it accepts both "," and "." as decimal separator, which is great!
- it shows already saved numbers with "," e.g. "5,89" which I don't like much, but is actually correct

  in GChrome, and Android built in browser:
- it has no effect, at least I couldn't find any

Here is another very nice article, and a table showing which browser in which operating system supports what: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localizatione

Conclusion: as browser support is not good, and definitely not consistent, as FF usage is very low at the moment, but GChrome's behavior (of silently omitting the comma when you type it) is just horrible, I will have to either switch to text field and do some custom magic for validation/parsing etc. or just leave the default behavior and let users hate me.

Comment: It's truly appalling that Chrome doesn't respect the locale's number separators. Apparently it's been an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141169) since 2012. (In my experience, the built-in date, number, etc. form controls are generally poor anyway, but still, they should...work.)

Answer (score 0):

When handling user input in `input` elements, use the `input` event, not `keyup`. `input` fires whenever the value is changed (by keystroke, right-click and paste, increment/decrement buttons provided by the browser, etc.).

Then, in a browser that supports `type="number"`, use `valueAsNumber` to access the numeric value. You can reliably fall back to `value` to access the text in the field and then do your manipulation of it.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("input", function (){                  // `input` event
    var value;
    if ("valueAsNumber" in this) {                     // Use `valueAsNumber` if provided
        value = this.valueAsNumber;
    } else {
        value = +this.value.trim().replace(/,/g, "."); // Use `value` if not, convert to num
    }
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

(Note that there are lots of way to convert to number; I've used the unary `+` above. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number/51155061#51155061) for details.)

Comment: I am afraid that neither the type of event, nor the valueAsNumber changes anything regarding my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can change that in Ruby, in your controller action :

`params[:myparam] = params[:myparam].gsub(',','.').to_f`

But you can also add this in your model with a `before_validation` hook.

Doing it in Ruby is convenient because :

- It is back end. So you don't really care if front end change is successful or not. For example when javascript is disabled in the browser
- It allows to leave the comma in the browser if this is the official separator in your country.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if I don't change the input field to type="text" , the requests don't reach backend at all, as they don't pass html5 validation, so I don't believe this could work

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't reach your controller whether you use rails form helper `text_field` instead of  `number_field`. Is that another issue ?