# Pushing a string value as an integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, push

I am trying to push some values to an empty array that I am getting from an api call. When the values are `console.logged`, they appear like this:
`POP: 7758`
but when I push them to the array
`array.push(item);`
and `console.log(array)`, they appear like this:
`["7758"]`
How can I get these values to be numbers or integers? I need to summarize the array once all the items are pushed there.

Comment: If it appears as `["7758"]` in `console.log(array_object)`, the code has added a string value (compare `console.log(["1",2])`). *If you don't want to add strings, don't add strings.* Logging a string with `console.log(message_str)` won't include the quotes around the message string (vs. `console.log("1")`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do `array.push(+item)`

Comment: Yes, this worked correctly. The results are now `[7758, 2772, etc...]`.

Comment: @gwydion93, happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse that string to number using `parseInt()`:

```js
var item = '7788';
var array = [];
array.push(parseInt(item));
console.log(array);
```

But if your string is also expected to have floating values then you need to use `parseFloat()`:

```js
var item = '7788.11';
var array = [];
array.push(parseFloat(item));
console.log(array);
```

So, it is always better to use `parseFloat()` as it works for both decimal/non-decimal numbers.

Comment: This also worked and I liked that you included the `parseFloat` option for nonintegers.

Comment: @gwydion93 glad to help :)