# Instead of addition, float numbers are getting concat in jQuery when I try to sum these

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 float numbers, on which I want to perform mathematical addition operation. But, in jQuery, these are interpreted as strings and getting concatenated. Below is my code:

```
var final_premium = Math.round((Base_Premium + ADB_Premium + 
        ATPD_Premium + WOP_Add_Riders_Premium));
```

I have **also tried parsing these into int and float** before operation but it didn't work out. Code for the approach, I tried:

```
ATPD_Premium = parseFloat($("#ATPD_Premium").text()).toFixed(2);
```

Any thoughts for the solution on this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example which includes sample values for your variables. See the help section on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also use `typeof` to verify the types of your variables. The function `toFixed` returns a `String`.

Comment: `.toFixed` converts it *back* to a string.  Remove the `.toFixed` or add it only to the final value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Converting String to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically **toFixed()** function converting it to string, that's why concatination is happening.
Use it like this.

```
final_premium = Math.round((+Base_Premium + +ADB_Premium + +ATPD_Premium + +WOP_Add_Riders_Premium));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the variables in `Number()`. foe Ex: `Number(Base_Premium) + Number(ADB_Premium)`