# My mini calculator isn't working. Please read description

Tags: javascript, html, math, addition

I am trying to make a calculator in javascript and it is not working. When I try to do, say 1 + 1 it gives me 11 and this is the same for all the numbers here is my code:

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var fullEquat = document.getElementById("equation");
var add1 = slider1.value;
var add2 = slider2.value;

output.innerHTML = slider1.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider1.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
slider2.oninput = function() {
    add1 = slider1.value;
    add2 = slider2.value;
    equals = add1 + add2;
  fullEquat.innerHTML = slider1.value + "+" + slider2.value + "=" + equals;
}
slider1.oninput = function() {
    add1 = slider1.value;
    add2 = slider2.value;
    equals = add1 + add2;
  fullEquat.innerHTML = slider1.value + "+" + slider2.value + "=" + equals;
}
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
}
.equal {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100pt;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500" class="slider" id="myRange1">
    +
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500" class="slider" id="myRange2">
</div>
<p class="equal">=</p>
<p id="output" class="output"></p>
<p id="equation" class="equat"> + = </p>
```

Comment: try `add1 = +slider1.value;` or `add1 = parseFloat(slider1.value);` - same with all other values you get, since they will be Strings unless you make them Numbers ... `"1" + "1" === "11"` in javascript

Comment: The `.value` property is always a string, not a number. You can use `Number()` to transform the value to a number, or simply the `+` prefix operator.

Comment: @Pointy how do i use the Number() im a super noob at javascript

Comment: you can do like this `equals = +add1 + +add2;`

Comment: @firatozcevahir that is even shorter, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Converting String to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value property returns you a string, you can use a simple trick to multiply it with 1 like add1 = slider. value * 1. and it will give you a number

Answer (score 2):

When you declared `add1 = slider1.value; add2 = slider2.value;` you got a string instead of a number... you should put them inside a Number() like this

```
add1 = Number(slider1.value);
add2 = Number(slider2.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.value` property return a string
you have to use `.valueAsNumber` to get a number

sample code:

```js
const calcForm = document.forms['form-calculation']
  ,  pOutput   = document.getElementById('p-output')
  ;
calcForm.oninput=_=>
  {
  calcForm['range-1'].nextElementSibling.textContent = calcForm['range-1'].value
  calcForm['range-2'].nextElementSibling.textContent = calcForm['range-2'].value

  pOutput.textContent = calcForm['range-1'].valueAsNumber 
                      + calcForm['range-2'].valueAsNumber
  }
```

```css
form { width: 20em; }
input[type="range"] {width: 80%;  }
label { font-size:2em; font-weight: bold;  text-align: center; display: block; width: 80%;}
```

```html
<form name="form-calculation">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500"   name="range-1"><span>500</span> 
  <label>+</label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500" name="range-2"><span>500</span>
  <label>=</label>
</form>
  <p id="p-output" class="output">1000</p>
```

Comment: this is a very good coding job, but I don't know what most of the keywords mean. I wanted to try to stick with stuff I know. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @hacker19374 everything is on msn, for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling