# jQuery only using whole numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I currently have a form that draws a circle based on user input and outputs the diameter in the console as well. However, when I input a number with a decimal, it just converts it to a whole number. For example if I input 5.68, it takes my input as 5. How do I make it so that It recognized decimal numbers?

https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/wsgfhjLc/215/

```
$(function() {
  $('.circle').hide();
  $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseInt($("#outer_diameter").val());
    var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 10);
    console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
    /*const $circalc = (2 * Math.PI * ($outer_diameter / 2)).toPrecision(6);*/
    $('.circle').css({
      height: (2 * $converted),
      width: (2 * $converted),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  })

  $('.circle2').hide();
  $('#inner_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $inner_diameter = parseInt($("#inner_diameter").val());
    var $converted_2 = ($inner_diameter * 10);
    console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
    $('.circle2').css({
      height: (2 * $converted_2),
      width: (2 * $converted_2),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle2').fadeIn(300);
  })
});
```

Comment: `parseInt()` creates an integer. As you should have learned in math class, integers are whole numbers without fractions. Use `parseFloat()` if you want fractions.

Comment: Thank you. How would I restrict it to 3 decimal places?

Comment: Please put your [mcve] here, not on jsFiddle

Comment: Check out the following links they will assist you with your issue... [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: When I do var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").toFixed(3).val());  I get an error though. Same thing if it is $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val().toFixed(3));

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the value returning is indeed a `typeof number`?

Comment: `parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3)`

Comment: I am not sure, I am new to JS and jquery. I just know in the console it returns the correct output number. https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/wsgfhjLc/265/

Comment: Right BUT, is that number being logged an actual number or a string? This is important.

Comment: To add to j08691's comment, a sample should be *minimal*. Most of the sample code is irrelevant to the question and thus should be removed.

Comment: RE: "How would I restrict it to 3 decimal places?" Outside of asking for clarification, [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you have questions beyond what you originally asked, first check whether the question has already been asked, and post a new question if not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat()` rather than `parseInt()`. This will keep the fractions.

When you display the result later, use `toFixed(3)` to specify the number of digits to show.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.circle').hide();
  $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val());
    var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 10);
    console.log($outer_diameter.toFixed(3), $converted.toFixed(3));
    /*const $circalc = (2 * Math.PI * ($outer_diameter / 2)).toPrecision(6);*/
    $('.circle').css({
      height: (2 * $converted),
      width: (2 * $converted),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  })

  $('.circle2').hide();
  $('#inner_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val());
    var $converted_2 = ($inner_diameter * 10);
    console.log($inner_diameter.toFixed(3), $converted_2.toFixed(3));
    $('.circle2').css({
      height: (2 * $converted_2),
      width: (2 * $converted_2),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle2').fadeIn(300);
  })
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, use unary `+`, as described in some answers to "[Converting String to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2843897/90527)"

Comment: @outis There are many ways, I don't feel the need to mention more than one when I answer.