# convert innerhtml to a number and make calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple material calculator, but when I sum value, i get 27002700 instead of 5400
so i tryed to push it to an array and use .map and Number,
I rewrote it like 10 times. i am out of ideas .

```js
const heightValue = document.querySelector(".height-value")
const tottalDiv = document.querySelector(".tottal-div")

let heightArr = []
function rangeSlide2(value){
  heightValue.innerHTML = value;
}
heightArr.push(heightValue.innerHTML)
function tottal() {
 let tonum = heightArr.map(Number)
  tottalDiv.innerHTML = tonum + tonum;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range" id="height-range" min="2000" max="3500" step="100" value="2700" onchange="rangeSlide2(this.value)" onmousemove="rangeSlide2(this.value)">
        <span class="height-value">2700</span>
        
        <div class="button-div">
      <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="tottal()">tottal</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tottal-div">0</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Converting String to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843897/javascript-converting-string-to-number)

Comment: you could maybe try `valueAsNumber` instead `onchange="rangeSlide2(this.valueAsNumber)"`

Comment: calculation input hight value and sum it with it self 2700 + 2700 should be 5400 insted of 27002700

Comment: try `Number(input.value) * 2`. get the input element using `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `map` will be an array and when you try to sum two arrays both with one value it will be converted to `string`, so `[2700]` + `[2700]` same as `'2700' + '2700' = '27002700'`.

So, I think what you need is `reduce` method, to sum all values.

```js
const heightValue = document.querySelector(".height-value")
const tottalDiv = document.querySelector(".tottal-div")

let heightArr = []
function rangeSlide2(value){
  heightValue.innerHTML = value;
}
heightArr.push(+heightValue.innerHTML)
function tottal() {
  let tonum = heightArr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item)
  tottalDiv.innerHTML = tonum + tonum;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range" id="height-range" min="2000" max="3500" step="100" value="2700" onchange="rangeSlide2(this.value)" onmousemove="rangeSlide2(this.value)">
        <span class="height-value">2700</span>
        
        <div class="button-div">
      <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="tottal()">tottal</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tottal-div">0</div>
```

Comment: ohh lol i tryed reduce method before but i guess did something wrong . Thank you )

Comment: hey i just notice + that you added to push, could you just give me an article to read about it or just maybe explain to me in few words ? thank you. that is actually why it didnt worked out when i used reduce method)

Comment: @AlexRaskatov, it simply used to convert string to number, you can read more about it here [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)